# Auth::user()->notifications not working in laravel live server

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7

I am trying to get users notification like this

```
Auth::user()->notifications
```

but it is not fetching notification for this user. It is working fine on localhost and it was also working fine on live server before i have just changed aws instance and database connection now.

It is also working fine in api can't get why it is not working in laravel blade

Comment: what is an error?

Comment: giving empty array

Comment: database is having data

Comment: Make sure you have added "notifications" inUser model

Comment: like how can you give example? ?

Comment: see laravel [notification](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#using-the-notifiable-trait) docs